# How to validate ID number in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am new at this so be easy on me... :)

1. I need to validate if a the ID number that the user typed in my site is a valid ID.

How do I check it?

Do I need to use RegularExpressionValidator?

2. More over, I also need to validate the credit card number, I found a few RegularExpressions for that in the net but each one is different from the other and I am not sure which one to use..
   Does anyone know od a working expression that will suit all credit cards??

Thanks,
Tsil.

Comment: We don't know what a "valid ID" means in your application, you need to supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

You never *need* to use the RegexValidator, it's just handy sometimes.
EDIT: a Regex can only check for a string-pattern and can't do any calculations or other checks that require numbers as opposed to "sequences of digits".

It all depends on what you consider a valid "ID". Is any number "valid" or are there more rules?

For a creditcard number you also need to specify what you consider valid: just a number of digits (12 I think?) with maybe added dots or spaces? Or do you want to know whether that card itself is valid? That's a different problem entirely!

EDIT: for a SSN, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Structure).

Comment: I am talking about Social security number,

Comment: I know there is an algorithm to calculate that but I cn't find it and not sure how to use it...

Comment: regarding the Credit card, I want to make sure that the card number  is reall and no one made it up.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of ID are you talking about? A social security number or a User ID to login?

Since you are talking about it in the context of a Credit card and Regular Expression validators, I will assume that you are talking about a Social Security number.

Anyways, if you Are talking about Login controls or such please [go here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/security/login.aspx).

Regarding Social Security number, this depends on what country the person is from and how the individual country sets up their numbers, but to give you a little taste of what you might want to do, check out How to use [Regulat Expression Validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx).

However, Please, please, please **do not validate the credit card number yourself**. There are Bank Services that you can use for this, head over to [PayPal](http://paypal.com) and check their [API for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/paypal_c_aspnet.aspx), this will most certainly make your users feel more comfortable on your site.

**Also use SSL**.

**Regular expression validator example**

```
<%@ language="C#" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                    ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtName"     
                                    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$" />
</form>
```

If you want to try out some regular expressions head over to the greatest [resource there is.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) And don't forget to [read this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx).

You might also want to [read **User Input validation in ASP.NET** from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx) and [Learn ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/learn) from Microsoft has some great videos on [ASP.NET Security](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/security) that you might find usefull.